# Encoding Binary Data into Quantum Basis

Tags: programming, hamiltonian-simulation, machine-learning

I am working on implementing a paper on QNNs. I have successfully been able to resize a MNIST digit to be able to meet the size of quantum circuit. But I am not clear of how to convert the resized image into a format that will allow me to use it to apply to this circuit to see how label classification works in this quantum circuit.

Any suggestions would be mostly appreciated.